# How do you bring up the window showing Tasks?

Tags: tasks, interface

There's a window that shows Tasks -- it may be called the "reminder window".  It usually shows up when I log in, but somehow it got closed.  How do you bring this window up?

#### The Window

I'll describe this window in more detail, just in case I'm giving it the wrong name.

There's a report available (on the Reports tab) called Tasks & Appointments that shows all my open tasks.  The window I'm looking for is an abbreviated version of that report, showing just the type of task, the due date, and how many days it's overdue, along with a button to dismiss the task.

This window is a standalone pop-up window, meaning that you can drag it out of the way so you can work with the main Salesforce app in your browser.

This window normally pops up when I log in, but doesn't now.  Somehow I must have closed it.

#### What I've Tried

I've tried poking around in the Tasks & Appointments report to see if there's an option to pop up a window summary of it, but I haven't found anything.

I've searched on Google -- the only advice I found was to log out and log back in.  I tried *logging out and back in*, but the window doesn't come back up.

My browser's *pop-up blocker is disabled*, so that isn't stopping it.

In my Salesforce settings for activity reminders, *"trigger alert when reminder comes due" is checked*.  The "open a test reminder" button on that screen brings up a sample reminder window properly.

How can I bring this summary of Tasks window back up?

Answer (score 1):

It could be your personal settings.

1. Go to where your name is in the top right corner of the screen
2. Click on your name and select "My Settings"
3. Click on "Calendars and Reminders"
4. Make sure that "Trigger alert when reminder comes due" and check any other applicable settings.

Comment: That setting (to trigger alerts) was already checked.  All the other settings look right.  I even tried the "open a test reminder" button and it did bring up a window like it should.  Yet the tasks window I'm looking for still isn't around.  (By the way, is the window I'm looking for called the "reminder window"?)

Comment: @Mary have you tried resetting your browser settings. Then close your browser and re-open.

Comment: Just tried resetting and restarting as you suggested, but it had no effect.

Comment: @Mary Have you tried going to Setup>Customize>Activities>Activity Settings and make sure that "Enable Activity Reminders" checkbox. Let me know if this works so I can post as an answer.

Comment: Good idea, but I'm afraid it was already checked.

Comment: @Mary what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, version 44.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Given the pretty useful answers and suggestions brought up so far I can only think of one thing left; you have currently no open activities

Comment: also addition to this ans.. if there are open activities may be OP dismissed all activities

Comment: Hi Mary just curiosity; did you find out what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when this happens it is the browser settings.

1. In Chrome you would go to Settings>Advanced Settings>Privacy>Content Settings>Pop Up Blocker
2. Click on "Manage Exceptions"
3. Add Salesforce to your exceptions.

This would also be the place where you could see if you blocked it by accident. Sometime the browser will ask if you want to accept popups for a site and once you click on "no" the popup doesn't happen anymore. You can change it from block to allow.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that's not it.  To be sure, I just turned off all pop up blocking for my browser, logged out of Salesforce, then logged back in.  No Task window popped up.